# Single function comparison in custom Python classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, comparison

I often need to make a class I made comparable for various reasons (sorting, set usage,...) and I don't want to write multiple comparison functions each time. How do I support the class so I only have to write a single function for every new class?

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the problem is to create an abstract class a class can inherit and override the main comparison function (`diff()`) with the desired comparison method.

```
class Comparable:
    '''
    An abstract class that can be inherited to make a class comparable and sortable.
    For proper functionality, function diff must be overridden.
    '''
    def diff(self, other):
        """
        Calculates the difference in value between two objects and returns a number.
        If the returned number is
        - positive, the value of object a is greater than that of object b.
        - 0, objects are equivalent in value.
        - negative, value of object a is lesser than that of object b.
        Used in comparison operations.
        Override this function."""
        return 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.diff(other) == 0

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.diff(other) != 0

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.diff(other) < 0

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.diff(other) <= 0

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.diff(other) > 0

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.diff(other) >= 0
```

Comment: Ok, but the de-facto way of achieving this is the [`total_ordering` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)

Comment: @DeepSpace By implementing it in the Comparable class or the inheriting class instead of inheritance? Because the former is a helpful upgrade to the Comparable solution while the latter is an inadequate replacement as it requires at least two functions to be written in each class (three if you want to write the comparison in one place for easy changes)